# Add external IP addresses to bind9

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, bind9

I've setup a DNS Server with bind9 to resolve all local addresses within my network. I have some external IP addresses which I'd like to add as well. Is this possible with bind9? The external IP's reside on AWS(If that helps).

Comment: What exactly does *external IP addresses which I'd like to add* mean?  It's not clear what problem you're trying to solve.  Can you clarify this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

See below configuration file that you need to achieve your use case
 `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` file

```
 Sudo nano /etc/bind/named.conf.options
 forwarders {
 # Give here your IP
  };
```

For more information check below read too. https://askubuntu.com/questions/330148/how-do-i-do-a-complete-bind9-dns-server-configuration-with-a-hostname